# How would I search for the merged questions?

Tags: support, merged-questions

Searching for `merged:yes` doesn't seen to work. Nor does `ismerged:yes` or `duplicate:yes hasnotice:yes`.

How would I search for the merged questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most right way would be to go to [Annotated posts > locked > merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=locked&filter=merged). Though this search is not very flexible, as you can't specify another parameters.

The most close alternative using advanced search is `duplicate:yes locked:yes answers:0`, however on MSE the advanced search option does give two results less than the annotated posts; and on SO, otherwise, excess 302 results.

Comment: The difference is because not all merged questions are actually marked as duplicates of the questions they were merged into.